# Timeout "time" command in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I want to timeout "time" command. For example:

```
timeout -s 1 time sleep 5
```

I never get timeout. Is any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-s` option in `timeout` is for mentioning signal to send.

You just need to remove `-s`:

```
timeout 1 time sleep 5
```